# Complex Borel measures: If $X$ is a locally compact separable metric space, then weak convergence coincides with weak$^*$ convergence

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence, separable-spaces

Let

- $X$ be a topological space,
- $\mathcal C_b(X)$ the space of real-valued bounded continuous functions on $X$,
- $\mathcal C_c(X)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ with compact supports.
- $\mathcal M (X)$ the space of all **complex** Borel measures on $X$,
- $\mathcal M_{\mathbb R}(X)$ the space of all finite **signed** Borel measures on $X$, and
- $\mathcal M_+ (X)$ the space of all finite **non-negative** Borel measures on $X$.

For $\nu \in \mathcal M(X)$, let $|\nu| \in \mathcal M_+ (X)$ be its [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Variation_of_a_complex_measure_and_polar_decomposition). We endow $\mathcal M(X)$ with the total variation norm $[\cdot]$ defined by $[\nu] := |\nu|(X)$. Then $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ is a Banach space.

- A subset $M$ of $\mathcal M(X)$ is said to be **tight** if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $\sup_{\nu \in M}| \nu| (X \setminus K) <\varepsilon$.
- A subset $M$ of $\mathcal M(X)$ is said to be **bounded** if $\sup_{\nu \in M} [\nu] <\infty$.

Let $\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$. We define

- weak convergence by
  $$
  \mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_b(X),
  $$
- weak$^*$ convergence by
  $$
  \mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_c (X).
  $$

Previously, I proved that

> [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4570642/1019043) Let $X$ be a locally compact **separable** metric space and $\mu, \mu_n \in \mathcal M_\mathbb R (X)$ such that $\limsup_n [\mu_n] \le [\mu]$. Then $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$ if and only if $\mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$.

Now I want to extend above theorem to $\mathcal M(X)$, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be a locally compact **separable** metric space and $\mu, \mu_n \in \mathcal M (X)$ such that $\limsup_n [\mu_n] \le [\mu]$. Then $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$ if and only if $\mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$.

The proof is essentially the same as the original one. However, I write it down and hope that someone helps me verify it. It's likely that I made some subtle mistakes in the transition from finite signed measures to complex measures.

Could you please have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much!

---

**Proof:** One direction is obvious. Let's prove the reverse. We need the following lemmas, i.e.

- [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570444/every-locally-compact-separable-metric-space-is-a-radon-space) Let $X$ be a locally compact **separable** metric space. Then $X$ is a [Radon space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Radon_spaces).
- [Lemma 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914363/open-sets-with-compact-closure-containing-a-given-compact-set) Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$ and $U$ an open subset of $X$ such that $K \subset U$. Then there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $K \subset V \subset \overline V \subset U$ and $\overline V$ is compact.
- [Lemma 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572315/let-x-be-locally-compact-separable-and-mu-n-overset-rightharpoonup-mu) Let $X$ be a locally compact normal Hausdorff topological space. Let $\mu_n, \mu \in \mathcal{M}(X)$ such that $\mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$. Then for any open subset set $O$ of $X$,
  $$
  |\mu|(O) \leq \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\mu_n\right|(O) .
  $$
- [Lemma 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571939/prokhorovs-theorem-from-finite-signed-measures-to-complex-measures) Let $X$ be a topological space and $x, x_n \in X$. If every subsequence of $(x_n)$ has a further subsequence which converges to $x$. Then the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.
- [Prokhorov's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570472/references-for-prokhorovs-theorem-on-a-completely-regular-space) Let $X$ be completely regular topological space and $M$ a subset of $\mathcal M (X)$. If $M$ tight and bounded, then the closure of $M$ in $\sigma(\mathcal M (X), \mathcal C_b(X))$ is sequentially compact.

1. $(\mu_n)$ is tight.

By **Lemma 1**, $\mu$ is tight. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. There is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $|\mu| (K^c) <\varepsilon$. By **Lemma 2**, there is an open subset $O$ of $X$ such that $K \subset O$ and $K_\varepsilon := \overline O$ is compact. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\limsup_n |\mu_n|(X \setminus K_\varepsilon) &= \limsup_n \big [ [\mu_n]- |\mu_n|(K_\varepsilon) \big ] \\
&\le \limsup_n \big [ [\mu_n]- |\mu_n|(O) \big ] \\
&\le \limsup_n [\mu_n]- \liminf_n |\mu_n|(O) \\
&\le [\mu] - \liminf_n |\mu_n|(O).
\end{align}
$$

By **Lemma 3**,
$$
\limsup_n |\mu_n|(X \setminus K_\varepsilon) \le [\mu] - |\mu|(O) = |\mu|(X \setminus O) \le |\mu| (X \setminus K) <\varepsilon.
$$

2. $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$.

Let $\lambda$ be a subsequence of $\mathbb N$. By **Prokhorov's theorem**, there is a subsequence $\eta$ of $\lambda$ and $\hat \mu \in \mathcal M(X)$ such that $\mu_{\eta (n)} \rightharpoonup \hat \mu$ and thus $\mu_{\eta (n)} \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \hat \mu$ as $n \to \infty$. Notice that the weak$^*$ topology $\sigma (\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_c(X))$ is Hausdorff, so $\hat \mu = \mu$. The claim then follows from **Lemma 4**.